# Removing element from ArrayList through Iterator

Tags: java

I want to make a look up for entry in `ArrayList` and remove element if it's found, the simplest way I guess is through `Iterator`, here's my code:

```
    for (Iterator<Student> it = school.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
        if (it.equals(studentToCompare)){
            it.remove();
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println(it.toString());
        it.next();
    }
```

But something is wrong: instead of iterating through my `ArrayList<Student> school` I get using `it.toString()`:

```
java.util.ArrayList$Itr@188e490
java.util.ArrayList$Itr@188e490
...
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `List` has `.remove()`!!

Comment: You are doing a `toString()` of the iterator, not of `Student`

Comment: `ArrayList$Itr@188e490` is the address of the iterator itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not ?

```
school.remove(studentToCompare);
```

Use List [remove(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation).

And moreover

> It Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).

Comment: Could highlight the fact that it both returns true on success, AND that it removes the _first_ element; both having the cake and eating it given OP's question

Comment: Your answer is the preferred one. But the iterator will be useful when you are looping through the list and based on some condition you would like to remove an element from the list being inside the loop.

Answer (score 22):

`it` is a `Iterator`, not `Student`

```
for (Iterator<Student> it = school.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    Student student = it.next();
    if (student.equals(studentToCompare)){
        it.remove();
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println(student.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this output is because you are calling `toString()` method on `iterator` and not on the `Student` object.

You can remove `student` from the list by using

```
school.remove(student);
```

Also, if you want to print meaningful Student object information when you write

```
System.out.println(student);
```

Override `toString()` method for it as `System.out.println()` statement would internally call `toString()` on `student` object.

```
public String toString() {
    return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName
            + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Iterator<Student> it = school.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    **Student st** = it.next();
    if (**st**.equals(studentToCompare)){
        it.remove();
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println(**st**.toString());
}
```

OR

```
school.remove(school.indexOf(studentToCompare));
```

OR

```
school.remove(studentToCompare);
```

The latter two examples assume `school` is a `List`.